# infinispan JDG key getting removed automatically

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan, spring-cache

we have a JDG cluster with 5 nodes with repl_async mode

One of the key in the cache ( which is around 200 kb ) is getting removed from cache every few seconds

We are sure that from the application we have not evicted this key

Cache heap is set to 7 GB where the usage is only around 3-4 GB

Is there any other configuration to be checked ?

No of entries in this cache is 110 and the max entries is 2000

Answer (score 1):

The only ways for entries to be removed without a direct removal from the user is either if the entry has been evicted (which it sounds like it shouldn't have been) or through expiration, which is configured on the cache or when inserting the entry.

You can read more about expiration at http://infinispan.org/docs/dev/user_guide/user_guide.html#expiration_anchor

Answer (score 0):

Eviction would only remove it from memory, if there is a persistence configure it will reload it on access, if not it works similar as expiration (but not cluster wide!)

A lifecycle for expiration can be added as server wide default within the configuration or individiually for each entry with the .put(...) API